# Amelia correlation analysis

Tags: r, imputation

I want to perform a correlation analysis with imputed datasets from the original dataset "freetrade" from Amelia package. 
So first I loaded the data and created multiple datasets with amelia function:

```
library(Amelia)
data <- freetrade %>%
  select(c("country", "tariff", "pop", "gdp.pc", "intresmi", "fiveop", "usheg"))
am <- amelia(data, m=5, idvars=1)
```

Now I would like to perform a correlation between tarriff, pop and gdp.pc. I absolutely did not find anything on the Internet on how to do it, only for the mice package "micombine.cor()".
I tried transforming the imputed data sets "am" into the data type mids, since micombine.cor() only takes the data type mids:

```
as.mids(am)
```

but there is only an error called : "Imputation index `.imp` not found"
Do you have any methods on how to perform the correlation analysis? I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the manual page for Amelia, particularly the part that tells how `amelia` returns its results. Trying the examples is also very useful. The example on the manual page uses the data set `africa` which is included in the package and seems roughly similar to yours:

```
am <- amelia(africa[, 3:7])    # Just using the numeric variables
cor(am$imputations[[1]])       # For the first imputed data set
lapply(am$imputations, cor)    # For all five imputed data sets
```

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for your help! I did not find it in the manual though, so I wanted to know, if you know how to combine those results then?

Comment: To get the manual, type the command `?amelia`. You should always read the manual page before trying to use a function. You can take the means to get the mean value of the correlation across the matrices or the minimum and maximum to get the range in values.

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, I noticed you first imputed only for the numeric variables here and then obtained the correlation for the whole dataset(s). Is there a way to obtain the correlations between only the numeric variables AFTER imputing? I would like to do this but wasn't sure how to subset to only numeric variables in the amelia object of imputed datasets.

Comment: Since I only gave `amelia` the numeric variables, it only has the numeric variables in the imputed data set. If you also imputed non-numeric variables, you need to restrict the correlations. To remove only column 5 (in the imputed data, not the original data): `lapply(am$imputations, function(x) cor(x[, -5]))` or to get columns 1, 3, and 5: `lapply(am$imputations, function(x) cor(x[, c(1, 3, 5)]))`.